# Change woocommerce product addons position in the product page

Tags: page-attributes

I need to change the product position of an addon called "misura anello" in the products (i use product add-ons plugin), i want to place it above the price, like the attributes...

i post to attach to images...

[image: using product addons]

[image: using attributes]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wanting to do this outside of the plugin, to future proof this from updates, you can use the global var in place of the $this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', array(  $GLOBALS['Product_Addon_Display'], 'display' ), 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', array(  $GLOBALS['Product_Addon_Display'], 'totals' ), 20 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for class-product-addon-display.php in plugin folder.
You need function __construct().

For me it worked like this:

```
// Addon display
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', array( $this, 'display' ), 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', array( $this, 'totals' ), 20 );
```